# Difference between Checkbox Field Inside Label and div?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Above Image shows u a checkbox inside label. Here, when I click the empty space other than the checkbox, the checkbox is checked. However, if I use the div element instead of the label and click the empty space, the checkbox is untouched. Whats the difference between label and div in this scenario!!!

HTML Code:

```
<div class="card">
 <h1>Fancy Checkbox</h1>
  <label class="fancy-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <i></i>
 </label>
```

CSS Code:

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:200');
  *,*::after{
     box-sizing:border-box;
            }
   .card{
      width: 600px;
      margin: 30px auto;
      padding: 20px 15px;
      border-radius:4px;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      align-items:center;
      font-family: Work Sans;
      box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     }

    .fancy-checkbox{
       position:relative;
       margin:15px 0px;
       overflow:hidden;
       display:block;
    }
    input{
     position:absolute;
     visibility:hidden;
     }
  input + i{
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius:20px;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

input + i::after{
    content:"";
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    float:left;
    border-radius:20px;
    transition: all 0.25s;
   }
```

I tried to use div instead of the label but not checking the checkbox.

Comment: Can you add your code

Comment: code added mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<label>` element is a bit special and can be linked to `<input>` elements.

As quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

> The label text is not only visually associated with its corresponding
>   text input; it is programmatically associated with it too. This means
>   that for example a screenreader will read out the label when the user
>   is focused on the form input, making it easier to what data should be
>   entered.
>
> Because the input has a label associated with it, you can click the
>   label to focus/activate the input, as well as the input itself. This
>   increased hit area provides advantages to anyone using a mouse to
>   activate the input.
>
> To associate the `<label>` with an `<input>` element in the above style,
>   you need to give the `<input>` an `id` attribute. The `<label>` then needs a
>   for attribute whose value is the same as the input's id.
>
> Alternatively, you can nest the `<input>` directly inside the `<label>`, in which case the `for` and `id` attributes are not needed because the association is implicit: